Coq - Are there functions which are provably equal but not definitionally equal?
In Coq, are there types A,B and functions f, g : A -> B such that f = g propositionally but f is not equal to g definitionally?
If the axiom of functional extensionality is assumed, this is obviously true. It's not clear to me whether there is an example here that doesn't use axioms.

If a = b non-definitionally, and f is a binary function, then f a = f b is a (likely non-definitional) equality of unary functions.

That's a great answer, thank you very much! As a follow up, can you think of any examples of a,b which are closed and propositionally equal but not equal? It would be interesting to strengthen the question to require A,B, f,g to be closed, but this could be a separate question.

If all the terms involved are closed, by canonicity any proof of f = g is convertible to refl, so necessarily f is convertible to g. This also assumes the proof of f = g to be closed, but obviously if you work under a context you can get garbage equalities like 0 = 1.

I realize this is more subtle than I originally thought.  I thought I would be able to also prove say Theorem foo : (fun x y : nat => x + y) = (fun x y : nat => y + x). without functional extensionality, but I realize I am probably wrong.  I think @Pierre-MariePédrot 's answer is more to the spirit of your question.  As he says, my above example f a = f b wouldn't work for closed a and b since they would have to be definitionally equal.  He should turn his comment into an answer.

But I also guess there are some subtleties around "canonicity" as well.  For example, is it known that canonicity holds for Coq?  Also, if we are talking about all possible types A, B, does canonicity hold for other types (and does it even make sense to talk about canonicity of types like (Nat -> Nat) -> Nat or SProp)?  See, for example, https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1026/does-the-canonicity-of-natural-number-imply-that-of-all-types .

In Pierre-Marie Pédrot's answer, the relevant canonicity theorem only needs to apply to the identity type not to an arbitrary type. I don't think that there is any formal proof that Coq (or rather its idealized theory PCUIC following metacoq to put aside implementation bugs) satisfy canonicity, but at least identity types do satisfy canonicity in MLTT+Pi+Sigma+Id+1 universe (as shown in this Coq dev).

Don't some of the coinductive definitions in Coq have closed terms that are provably equal but not judgmentally equal?

@kyod There is a proof of canonicity in MetaCoq here. It is a bit hard to read, but basically it says that (assuming normalisation), any inhabitant of an inductive type, in an axiom-free environment and the empty context, is convertible to a term which starts with a constructor.

@JasonRute Afaik, canonicity is usually a statement about closed terms of inductive types. Indeed, as soon as you start talking about functions, their body will live under a context, and so the statement has to be more general, because it needs to talk about open contexts too. This soon evolves into full-blown normalisation.

@DanDoel indeed, positive coinductive types break subject reduction so there are non-standard equality proofs between e.g. streams, typically η-expansion. But while this answers the question positively, this is a bug of the implementation rather than a property of CIC.

Stressing out the leading in Coq from the original question, here is an actual instance.

I assume this is very hard to find, as almost all models of type theory we have validate funext.
